# Need help parsing id3 tags asyncrhonously in node.js using id3-parser

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, id3

I have a folder full of mp3s that I would like to parse using id3-parser npm module so that I can return an rss feed. The id3-parser documentation says to use this structure:

```
id3.parse(filebuffer).then(function(tag){
  console.log(tag.title);
});
```

The id3-parser module uses the promise-a-plus module. The problem with my code is that the tag gets read at the very end of the stack. Here is my test code:

```
var id3 = require('id3-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir("podcasts", function (err, files) {
  files.forEach( function (file) {
    var stats = fs.statSync("podcasts/" + file);
    if (stats.isFile()) {
      var fbuff = fs.readFileSync("podcasts/" + file);
      id3.parse(fbuff).then( function (tag) {
        console.log("***"+tag.title);
      });
      console.log("Parsed id3 tag " + file);
    }
    console.log("Done file");
  });
  console.log("Done readdir");
});
```

The output is:

```
Parsed id3 tag test.mp3
Done file
Done readdir
***Title tag
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to properly wait for the tag to be parsed. Parsing should happen before I put it into the rss feed (have no trouble using the rss module to create that xml feed -- code not shown). I have been reading about promises and I am missing something. I am sure I just need to completely refactor my code, but not sure how to read every file (currently using readdir and forEach) and add each file to the feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var id3 = require('id3-parser')
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

function promiseFromCallback (fn) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return fn(function (err, result) {
      return err ? reject(err) : resolve(result)
    })
  })
}

function dirID3 (directory) {
  return promiseFromCallback(function (gotDir) {
    return fs.readdir(directory, gotDir)
  }).then(function (files) {
    return Promise.all(files.map(function (file) {
      var filePath = path.join(directory, file)
      return promiseFromCallback(function (gotStat) {
        return fs.stat(filePath, gotStat)
      }).then(function (stat) {
        return stat.isFile() ? promiseFromCallback(function (gotBuffer) {
          return fs.readFile(filePath, gotBuffer)
        }).then(function (fbuff) {
          return id3.parse(fbuff)
        }).then(function (tag) {
          return { path: filePath, tag: tag }
        }) : null
      })
    }))
  }).then(function (id3Items) {
    var result = {}
    id3Items.forEach(function (id3Item) {
      if (id3Item) result[id3Item.path] = id3Item.tag
    })
    return result
  })
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
dirID3('podcasts').then(function (dirInfo) {
  console.log('ID3 info for directory', dirInfo)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying to comprehend all the chained thens in your solution. Haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I need. Thanks :)